# How can I disable timestamps on PM2?

Tags: pm2

I wanted to use see timestamps on my log output from pm2, so I stopped the process and started it again with:

```
pm2 start www --log-date-format "MM/DD HH:mm"
```

Which successfully gave me timestamps. I now want to turn them off, but restarting doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete the process from PM2 with `pm2 delete www` and then add it back with `pm2 start www`.